# Upload binary without migration

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I am trying to upload a new version of the build and for some reason, I do not want to introduce migration in my current schema.

I have searched a lot but I could not find any answer to achieve this. If I upload my build like this and then upload the later versions with migrations, will it affect the later builds? (I know it should not, technically, but I have a few doubts!)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to migrate if your schema changes.  So assuming the schema has not changed later version will not be effected.

NB. Lightweight migration is simple to implement, a better approach would be to have a new schema version with every build.

Comment: You are right and I get how the migration works but I have a few reasons not to enter a migration in my current schema changes, will it affect my later builds?